# Cron Job using PM2 to Start Ghost?

Tags: node.js, cron, ghost-blog, pm2

I am using PM2 to keep Ghost (blogging platform) alive and I need a Cron Job to restart Ghost in the event of a server reboot. However, I am unsure of the proper code for the Cron Job.

I [read](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-start-ghost-with-cron/) that this is what I am to use:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/npm start /path/to/ghost/
```

but instead of using `npm start` should I replace it with `pm2 start index.js` which is what I use to start Ghost with PM2?

Note: I do not have root access and I cannot use `pm2 startup`. This is why I am using a Cron Job. Also this area is new to me; please provide examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I would put the pm2 command in the cron job.  To make sure pm2 starts your Ghost blog in the correct environment run the following command:

```
echo "export NODE_ENV=production" >> ~/.profile
```

and this is the command you will want to put in the cron job to start Ghost with pm2:

```
cd /path/to/ghost; pm2 start index.js --name ghost
```

You can checkout my [article](http://www.allaboutghost.com/keep-ghost-running-with-pm2/) on pm2 here for some more details and options.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Question - Do I need `@reboot` before `cd /path/...`?